# Meaning of [手ェ出]

Tags: translation, katakana, kana

[image]

Can't understand 手ェ出さないでよ part. If it was 手が出さない it would make sense. Maybe it is actually the same thing and both translates as "keep your hands on".

But I can't find any evidence of this grammar. Even wiktionary doesn't say there is another meaning for エ: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%82%A7